# No Reverse Match Found error in Django when using < > in URL

Tags: python, django

I'm having problems with my URL paths.

Whenever I remove -- `path('<query>/follow', views.follow, name='follow')` -- everything works fine. When I include it, the page with the link on it reveals `'Reverse for 'follow' with no arguments not found'` though I can manually type the follow path into the URL and it succeeds. Why is this and how can I fix it?

html

```
<a href="{% url 'follow' %}">Follow</a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.explore, name='explore'),
     path('happening/profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
     path('happening/', views.happening, name='happening'),
     path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
     path('home/likes/', views.likes, name='likes'),
     path('<query>/follow', views.follow, name='follow'),
     path('<query>/', views.profpage, name='profpage'),
]
```

views.py

```
def profpage(request, query):
    obj = User.objects.filter(username=query)
    if not obj:
        attempt = {'user':query}
        return render(request, 'error.html', attempt)

    try:
        obj2 = reversed(get_list_or_404(Comments, user=query))
    except:
        obj2= {}
    try:
        obj3 = get_list_or_404(Comments, user=query)
    except:
        obj3 = {}
    like_dict={}
    for x in obj3:
        likes = x.likes.all().count()
        like_dict[int(x.id)] = int(likes)

    img = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__username=query)
    for x in obj:
        obj = x
    for x in img:
        img=x


    content =      {'obj': obj,
                    'img':img,
                    'info':obj2,
                    'like_dict':like_dict,
                    'query':query,


                    }
    return render(request, 'profpage.html', content)

def follow(request, query):
    print("WORKING")
    return HttpResponse(request)
```

Comment: That is logical, you did not specify a value for `query`. You should write something like `{% url 'follow' query='queryval' %}` with `queryval` the value to add.

Comment: ty!!!!!!!!!!!!!!